404 responses for /users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}/number
For a new Banno/JH customer of our digital banking plugin, we retrieve the user's accounts, and for each one, make a call to /users/{userId}/accounts/{accountId}/number to get the full account number. We have successfully tested this flow with a different customer.
For the customer in question, two of their users have tested it so far and we're seeing the same issue - while the call to get the accounts for the user succeeds, when we make the subsequent call to the account number API for each account, for some of them we get a 404 response.
A couple representative URLs that return a 404 are:

https://{customer URL}/a/consumer/api/v0/users/6d7f3421-8a93-4f99-8a5b-a1ee158b890d/accounts/47d4abdd-bbdb-408f-803a-00784affaadb/number
https://{customer URL}/a/consumer/api/v0/users/6d7f3421-8a93-4f99-8a5b-a1ee158b890d/accounts/7ed6f414-29e0-40f1-823f-f695420eeeb6/number

A couple clues that may or may not be relevant:

the accountStatus is "Unknown" for both of the above
the masked account numbers that are returned in the initial accounts data have a non-numeric character in it (x50S0153, x50S0000)

In case it helps, the institution ID is 04b3ba00-413b-4e5d-85bd-12176cf9d664
Appreciate the attention and time to help us with this!

Can you confirm that the new customer has correctly configured their external application to grant the "Accounts with full account numbers" claim? If yes, please share an x-request-id for a failed request.

Yes, I personally walked the customer through granting that claim, and anyway, the error code would have been different if that was the case.
Unfortunately, we don't log the x-request-id.

@Sam I updated the plugin to collect x-request-id and asked the customer to try again. request ID is 40505f7e56b242b7535fc580289d203f

After looking into it further, this seems like an edge case. It's returning 404 because the payload is not providing an account number. The customer FI may want to open a support case with Symitar to populate those account numbers and/or figure out why it is not populated in the first place.
